# iphone - Calendar.app-like UITableView paging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an app which displays list of events in a tableview.
Users should be able to switch between different weeks, meaning table view should reload the data.
I want to make switching look nice :-)

I like how it is implemented Calendar.app in day-overview mode: you can swipe and switch between different days.
How can I make something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I used Tapku library :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...its quite easy to use and flexible to edit as per your usage.

[klazuka / Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)

Comment: It is not really what I was looking for